# Functions in Python in 3.4.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is this function not printing in the shell? I keep getting these things:

```
<function terms at 0x025BD3D8>
```

```py
def gdp_sections ():
    file1 = open("GDP_Section1All_Hist1.csv" , 'r')

    for i in range(7):
        file1.readline()

    a_tuple = []
    line = file1.readline()
    line = line.split(',')
    year = line[22:43]

    line = file1.readline()
    line = line.split(',')
    GDP_Change = line[22:43]

    differences = []

    for i in range (len(year)):
        a_tuple = ((year[i]), (GDP_Change[i]))
        differences.append(a_tuple)



    file1 = open("GDP_Section1All_Hist2.csv" , 'r')
    for i in range(7):
        file1.readline()

    a_tuple = []
    line = file1.readline()
    line = line.split(',')
    year = line[4:48]

    line = file1.readline()
    line = line.split(',')
    GDP_Change = line[4:48]

    for i in range (len(year)):
        a_tuple = ((year[i]), (GDP_Change[i]))
        differences.append(a_tuple)

    print(differences)


def terms():
    file2 = open('the_correct_presidents.txt','r')

    file2.readline()

    for line in range(1,12):
        line = file2.readline()
        line = line.strip().split(',')
        if len(line)>3:
            del line[1]
        name_of_president = line[0]
        term = line[1].split('-')
        year_started_term = int(term[0])
        year_ended_term = int(term[1])
        party = line[2]
        print (line)
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do?  What is it doing instead?  Do the contents of the files being read matter, and if so, what are they?

Comment: You should use the built-in [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html) module in Python if you are reading a CSV file instead of trying to parse it yourself.

Comment: Please go take a [Python Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/), because your code has... issues. Of all kinds. Once you get your code working, you should also take it over to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and get some input.

Answer (score 0):

How are you invoking `terms`? Make sure you include the parenthesis otherwise you are asking for the function object named `terms` which appears to be what you are seeing. Functions are first class objects in Python and thus can be used as values and printed.

In other words, are you saying this at the shell?

```
>>> print(terms)
```

When you really intend to mean this?

```
>>> print(terms())
```